# Prevent insert on trigger and perform an update instead

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a trigger that is raised after an insert or update. In case of an insert, I want to check if the record being inserted on table exists. If exists, then I want to ignore the insert and perform an update within trigger for that record. How can I do this? Is is possible to do it within an after insert,update trigger (not using instead of trigger)?

Comment: What do you mean by _record exists_?

Comment: Why not use the `instead of` trigger? It's perfect for when you don't want the original action to take place. Instead, in an after trigger, as well as performing the actions you desire, you'll also have to *undo* the undesirable action that you just let it perform.

Comment: I totally agree with Damien here. An Instead of trigger is designed for this specific type of action, while an after trigger is desinged for other actions.